# jQuery Stops Working Change from ID to Class?

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I want to use a jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave on multiple boxes in a table so I decided to change the ids to classes (just switching # to . in both the js file and html file) as outlined below. It stopped working!

I then tried using `$(document).on('.class',` and more recently `$(".class").live` based on different threads I found in stackoverflow - this didn't work either, so I reverted the code to my original modification - see below.

I'm fairly new to this so I may be missing something obvious, but I haven't found the solution thus far.

*The HTML File*

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="hover">
            <div class="list-group">

                <a class="list-group-item">
              <span class="text-success"></span><div class="hide">One</div><div class="show">hi</div></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*The JS File*

```
//Hides detail initially
$(".show").hide();
//Shows added detail upon hover and gets rid of title
$(".hover").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".show").show();
    $(".hide").hide();
})
//Returns to normal on mouseoff
$(".hover").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".show").hide();
    $(".hide").show();
})
```

***EDIT***

This was my bad, I was importing the Javascript files in the wrong order in my HTML file!

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3joyzqmf/

Comment: Please show us the broken code.  What you've posted above is working fine.

Comment: Should it be in document(ready) or window(load)?

Comment: DOM ready is typically most reliable for most of your jQuery code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

(multiple boxes in a table) that mean you need to use $(this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show").hide();
    //Shows added detail upon hover and gets rid of title
    $(".hover").on('mouseenter',function() {
        $(this).find(".show").show();
        $(this).find(".hide").hide();
    }).on('mouseleave',function() {
        $(this).find(".show").hide();
        $(this).find(".hide").show();
    });  
});
```

see demo [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nb3uvsvu/28/)

Comment: it should not like a live demo but its better to make that after document ready .. I'll update my answer

Comment: @user3190635 answer updated with a new code and demo .. this code is pro than previous one